# How to unstack a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have daframe like this:

```
df
0     ,SHIPMENT_NO,transport_mode,DATE_REFERENCE,ORGIN_COUNTRY_CODE,DEST_COUNTRY_CODE,WEIGHTTONS,loadFactor,emissions_co2Equivalents,SHIPMENT_ORIGIN_NAME,SHIPMENT_DEST_NAME,distanceKm,route_startLocation_wgs84_longitude,route_startLocation_wgs84_latitude,route_endLocation_wgs84_longitude,route_endLocation_wgs84_latitude    0,1120005499,Road,2020-08-03,DE,NL,7.756,38.70...
1     ,SHIPMENT_NO,transport_mode,DATE_REFERENCE,ORGIN_COUNTRY_CODE,DEST_COUNTRY_CODE,WEIGHTTONS,loadFactor,emissions_co2Equivalents,SHIPMENT_ORIGIN_NAME,SHIPMENT_DEST_NAME,distanceKm,route_startLocation_wgs84_longitude,route_startLocation_wgs84_latitude,route_endLocation_wgs84_longitude,route_endLocation_wgs84_latitude    1,1120005499,Road,2020-08-03,DE,NL,7.756,38.70...
```

**Expected Output**

```
SHIPMENT_NO transport_mode  DATE_REFERENCE  ORGIN_COUNTRY_CODE  DEST_COUNTRY_CODE   WEIGHTTONS  loadFactor  emissions_co2Equivalents    SHIPMENT_ORIGIN_NAME    SHIPMENT_DEST_NAME  distanceKm  route_startLocation_wgs84_longitude route_startLocation_wgs84_latitude  route_endLocation_wgs84_longitude   route_endLocation_wgs84_latitude 
    1120005499       Road            2020-08-03      DE                      NL                      7.756            38.70
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you presented as your DataFrame contains actually:

- the left column (below "df") - the index,
- ",SHIPMENT_NO,..." - the content of the only column, named "0".

As I see from the content column, it:

- starts with a comma,
- then there are comma separated column names,
- the next part is a number of spaces,
- the "values part" (the rest of the current row) starts with the
  repeated index value and then there are (also comma separated)
  values for each column.

To convert this DataFrame into "normal" DataFrame:

1. Create a function:

   ```
   def createRow(row):
       return pd.Series(row.vals.split(',')[1:], index=row.names.split(',')[1:])
   ```
2. Then run:

   ```
   result = df[0].str.split(r'(?<=[a-z]) +(?=\d)', expand=True)\
       .rename(columns={0: 'names', 1: 'vals'})\
       .apply(createRow, axis=1)
   ```

Notes:

1. `str.split(...)` splits column named "0" into 2 columns. The splitting
   regex contains:

   - a *lookbehind* for a letter (the last letter in last column name),
   - a sequence of spaces (this is actually the "split point"),
   - a *lookahead* for a digit (corresponding to the index value).

   This way 2 columns are created:

   - *0* - column names,
   - *1* - the index and values for each column.
2. `rename(...)` changes column names to *names* and *vals*.
3. `apply(...)` applies *createRow* function to each row.
   The result is a *Series* containing:

   - the content of *vals* column, split on each comma, but without the
     first element (an empty string before the first comma),
   - the content of *names* column, split on each comma, but without the
     first element (the index), as the index.
4. All these *Series* objects (resulting from invocation of *createRow*
   on each source row) are then concatenated into the output DataFrame.
   Index values from each source *Series* are now column names and values
   of respective fields are now values of corresponding columns.
5. This code relies on an assumption that each row contains (after the index)
   as many values as column names.
6. All columns in *result* are of *object* type, since they were created
   from splitting of a string.
   So probably you should change the type of each column to either *float*
   or *int* (if needed).